# ORA-00903:invalid table name

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I have the following code in `PLSQL`:

```
Declare
    tablename varchar2(20):='emp'; 
    drop_stmt  varchar2(2000);

begin
    drop_stmt:='drop table :1 ;';
    --dbms_output.put_line(drop_stmt); 
    execute immediate drop_stmt using tablename;
end;
```

Results in:

> ORA-00903:invalid table name
>
> ORA-06512: at line 8

However when I run:

```
drop table emp ;
```

it just successfully runs. What may be the cause of this error?

Comment: Identifiers (table names, column names and so forth) cannot be bound. If you really have to use dynamic SQL you need to, after performing some sort of validation, hard code them(concatenate)

Comment: @Barbaros Why have you created a new tag for this question? Specific error codes make poor tags, those should be included in the body but not as a tag. If we'd create a tag for every error code SO would be riddled with them.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Hi, There are other tags which are prefixed as "ORA-", and this is nothing different than those. That make questions more classified, don't they..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan See [Do we really need a tag for every error code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274616/7296893). There's some disputes about the sensibility of these ORA- tags. Until that's settled, I think there's no need to increase the number of these. Since the question already contains the error code in both body and title, it does little for findability.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use this one:

```
drop_stmt:='drop table '||tablename; -- without ";" at the end of string
--dbms_output.put_line(drop_stmt); 
execute immediate drop_stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try this one.